# How to use preceding-sibling?

Tags: webdriver

```
<div id="ResultPanel" class="panel-body table-responsive">
   ::before
   <div id="ResultLoader" class=""></div>
   <h4 id="screenName">
      TestScreen
      <small>
      first
      </small>
   </h4>
</div>
```

I want to get the text from `<h4>` tag only, not along with the `<small>` tag text. When I am trying to get xpath of `<h4>` tag, it shows text as "TestScreen first". I am using

```
//*[@id='ResultPanel']/descendant::h4[@id='screenName']
```

Comment: I want to get text from h4 tag only not along with the small tag text when i am trying to get xpath of h4 tag it will showing text as "TestScreen first". I am trying //*[@id='ResultPanel']/descendant::h4[@id='screenName']

Comment: Please take more care with your formatting. If your question is hard to read, you won't get any answers. Please have a look at the edit history to see what was changed.

Comment: @Unheilig: When adding HTML-style tags like `<h4>` please make sure to put them into backticks so they will be shown as code and not being parsed.

Comment: plz help me to getting text from h4 tag only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following locator:

```
//*[@id='ResultPanel']/descendant::h4[@id='screenName']/text()[1]
```

I have tested it in Chrome Developer Tools is working like a charm.